# Flutter ListView not updating after setState, using StatefulWidget as items

Tags: flutter

A page contains a `ListView` whose `itemBuilder` returns a `StatefulWidget`, but after calling setState in this page, new data retrieved but ListView will not update until scrolling current existing items out of screen.

Replacing items with `StatelessWidget` works but my items need to be stateful because each of them has some animations.

How do I refresh the `ListView`?

---

```
  ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: listMarginTop, bottom: marginBottom),
    controller: scrollController,
    itemCount: cellCount,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(marginLeft, verticalSpacing, marginRight, 0),
        height: itemHeight,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: itemWidth,
              height: itemHeight,
              child: getItem(index * 2, Size(itemWidth, itemHeight)),///return a StatefulWidget
            ),
            Container(
              width: itemWidth,
              height: itemHeight,
              child: getItem(index * 2 + 1, Size(itemWidth, itemHeight)),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Please share some code to see your implementation and help you out, thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.

I have added to my Listview : key: UniqueKey()

And it works well, no need anything else :)

Comment: Thanks man, this was so easy and worked with my TextFields that wouldn't update as well

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setState()` function inside your `getItem()` function when your data changes in order to apply them to your `Listview` items, this is supported by the fact that your data changes when you scroll items out of the screen:

```
   getItem(){
     //your implementation
     setState();
   }
```

Comment: An empty setState() is a code smell.  You should make your change inside the closure passed to setState.